Get unique file path with numeric suffix in parentheses
I'm looking for a function that can handle cases where the input file path already contains a numeric suffix in parentheses. The current implementation of my get_unique_path function increments the numeric suffix by one until it finds a path that doesn't exist. However, this approach fails when the input file path already contains a numeric suffix.
For example, if the input file path is example(1).txt, the function will incorrectly append another set of parentheses and a number, resulting in example(1)(2).txt. Instead, I want the function to check the base path for existing parentheses and increment the numeric suffix accordingly.
Here's my current implementation:
def get_unique_path(file_path: str, suffix: str) -> Optional[str]:
    base_path = os.path.splitext(file_path)[0]
    attempt = 1
    while True:
        path = f"{base_path}({attempt + 1}){suffix}"
        
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            return path
        
        attempt += 1

I'd like to modify this function to handle cases where the input file path already contains a numeric suffix in parentheses. Can anyone suggest a solution?
It should try to create a path without a numeric suffix first, and then skip (1) and move directly to (2).

If your question is a programming question, requiring knowledge of programming languages other than unix shell scripting languages, ask on Stack Overflow.

And if you get example(2).txt as input but there's no example(1).txt nor example(3).txt but there is a example(4).txt and a example(123123123).txt, which should it pick?

The obvious first step is to check whether or not the file_path already contains a number in parentheses, and strip it if it does. We can use the re module to perform that operation.
One possible implementation is:
import re
from pathlib import Path

re_marker = re.compile(r"(?P<prefix>.*)\(\d+\)$")


def get_unique_path(file_path: str | Path) -> str:
    file_path = Path(file_path)
    parent = file_path.parent
    base = file_path.stem
    if mo := re_marker.match(base):
        base = mo.group("prefix")

    count = 1
    while True:
        new_path = parent / f"{base}({count}){file_path.suffix}"
        if not new_path.exists():
            return str(new_path)
        count += 1

Here are some simple tests:
>>> get_unique_path('/tmp/foo')
'/tmp/foo(1)'
>>> # create /tmp/foo(1)
>>> open('/tmp/foo(1)', 'w').close()
>>> # check again
>>> get_unique_path('/tmp/foo')
'/tmp/foo(2)'
>>> # pass in a filename that already contains a number
>>> get_unique_path('/tmp/foo(1)')
'/tmp/foo(2)'


To handle cases where the input file path already contains a numeric suffix in parentheses, you can use regular expressions to extract the base path and the numeric suffix.
Use re.search(r'(.*)\((\d+)\)(\.[^.]+)$', file_path) to match the input file path. Then, increment the numeric suffix and construct the new path. If no match is found, use the original logic to append a numeric suffix and increment it until a path that doesn't exist is found.
if match:
    base_path = match.group(1)
    count = int(match.group(2))
    file_extension = match.group(3)

    ...
else:
    ...

